# On Windows: How to open file with “Open with…” command in context menu correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

When I use the context menu command "Open with..." within Windows 7, the OS opens a new instance of my Electron application. I would prefer, that if the application is already running, the file to be opened will be opened within the already opened instance and not in a new one.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`app.makeSingleInstance()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.37.7/docs/api/app.md#appmakesingleinstancecallback) function, there's an example in the docs.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think this doesn't depend on windows (like open with settings) & it's a application specific setting (if exists).
I did a little search and found this link, maybe useful ;)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-single-instance

Comment: I think this does the same as above, but I try to keep the third party modules less. Thanks anyway.